# mysqldump store null as blank

Tags: null, mysql, hana

I use mysqldump to create a dump of my data table. The only problem is, that mysql stores a null value as **/N** and if I want to import the created CSV file into HANA, /N is not known as null but as varchar.

Is there a way to skip the null values during dumping or can I just replace /N with a blank?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,there are no options for handling the output of NULLs.
You could try to replace NULLs with empty in your table:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET columnname= '' where columnname is null
```