# On export, is there a way to not include nulls on INSERT?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using the MySQL Workbench, we can export schemas just fine, but it often leads to INSERT commands of the form:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `user`
    (`id`, `name`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1,'Taylor Swift',NULL);
```

But I'd like to have it read:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `user`
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Taylor Swift');
```

Is this possible?

If it's not possible with the Workbench, is there a command-line argument that would accomplish this with `mysqldump`?

I tried searching other posts on SO, but no luck and there doesn't seem to be a checkbox option available under the `Advanced Options...` area.  The common use case is exporting and re-importing data into different environments where columns like `description` may not exist.  I fully understand that I can do an `ALTER TABLE` to drop the column before exporting.

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182061/mysqldump-store-null-as-blank), but I'd ideally like to do it with the Workbench.

Comment: not sure if Workbench can do this. Usually you need create views to skip columns for export/import.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this.  The format produced by default is correct and valid, so I'm at a loss as to what problem you believe the additional info causes.

Comment: As stated in the question, if I need to import the data to an environment where the optional column doesn't exist, I would need to modify the dump or drop the column for exporting. If there is a better way to do this, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The normal backup process in MySQL Workbench (which is using the server's mysqldump tool) cannot omit individual columns. But you have several other options:

1. Use the table export wizard and export as csv. This assumes your target application can handle csv.
2. Create a view with only the columns you want exported (as suggested by Tim3880).
3. Instead of adjusting the source try adjusting the target. Can it be change to ignore specific columns?